# Get the newest value in the onClick() function

Tags: reactjs

My application is a counter.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

 function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const add = () => {
    setCount(count+1)
    console.log(count) // Here I want to get the updated count
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={add}>ADD</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The issue is that I can't get the value of `count` inside `add` function, I only get the previous value. I know that this is happening because useState is async. But how to get the updated value inside `add` function without using useEffect?   link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-feynman-k5b73?file=/src/App.js:0-377

Comment: Why does it matter? logically you can just log `count+1` if you want the current count.

Comment: I think he has used `count` example just to demonstrate what he is trying to achieve.
That I believe is executing a function after `setCount` without using `useEffect`. 
Not sure if that is possible at all.

Comment: Yeah, Why not use `useEffect`.

Comment: Using an `useEffect` hook is the pattern you should use though. `Add` should do one thing, update state, the effect should do the component side-effect.

Comment: @Ramesh, i need this in my application, this example is just the idea. In my real application i have to dispatch something in the store, now i'm doing this with useEffect. But the issue appears when i add the value (dispatch), because after leaving the page and accessing  it back in the result i add again the value. This is why i'm looking for a method to dispatch inside onClick function, not inside useEffect.

Comment: @Asking That's okay you can just write an if statement and check if you want to dispatch an action or not. You can also add all the dependencies that should trigger the `useEffect` when they change.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example of your code? I'm wondering why some internal component state is so coupled to your redux state.

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating the state and the new state depends on the previous state then you should update it this way:

```
  const add = () => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }
```

regarding `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(count);
}, [count])
```

The above code runs every time the count changes but since you said something about dispatching an action and you don't want to dispatch it every time you can do things conditionally:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(count === 5) {
   console.log('Don't dispatch anything here');
 } else {
   console.log('Dispatch here');
 }
}, [count])
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: as @Drew Reese pointed out in the comments, mutating state is generally bad idea. So you should copy the variable before and mutate *that*. See this revised code:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

 function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const add = () => {
    let count2 = count
    setCount(++count2)
    console.log(count2) //here you get the updated count :)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={add}>ADD</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Original answer (this is incorrect as you can't edit constants anyways)

You can use pre-incrementing in javascript to do this. Essentially it increments the value but changes the variable too.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

 function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const add = () => {
    setCount(++count)
    console.log(count) //here you get the updated count :)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={add}>ADD</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

More info on pre-incrementing in Javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment).

Comment: Mutating state object is an anti-pattern in react.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the default App functional component

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

 function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const add = () => {
    setCount(count+1)
    console.log(count) //here i want to get the updated count
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={add}>ADD</button>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `useEffect` in order to cater your requirment. Beacuse setState did not have callback functionality.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react";

 function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count);
 },[count]);


  const add = () => {
    setCount(count+1)
    //console.log(count) //here you get the updated count :)
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={add}>ADD</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not make your add function like this

```
const add = () => {
    const newState = count + 1;
    setCount(newState)
    console.log(newState) // Here I want to get the updated count
}
```